# How to detect that the 25000 request per day limit has been reached in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm working on a website using the Google Maps Javascript API v3.

The free version of the API is limited by 25000 requests a day. But what happens if this limit is reached?

Is there a way to detect that the request limit has been reached so a fallback Google Maps Image API map can be displayed instead?

Comment: Isn't this limit through the client IP?

Comment: Yes, but what's the API's behaviour?

Comment: Not sure. Unless you're proxying the request through your server, I don't see what the problem is. Since the map load request comes through the client machine, it's essentially 25,000 unique map loads per day per user (I think this is the case). According to their FAQ, you'd have to hit this 90 days in a row.

Comment: "25,000 unique map loads per day per user" If only that were true ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usage limit is based on site or application, not the client IP address.

You can use the Google API console to monitor your usage if you add an API key to each of your map requests. I have not seen a way to query the usage programmatically.
https://code.google.com/apis/console

Per the comment below by @alds, it does appear that JS Maps API v3 and Static Maps API are separate services, therefore having separate request limits.  Falling back to a static Google map image could help.

This also explains the usage limits in better detail:
http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/11/understanding-how-maps-api-usage-limits.html

Comment: That's a huge bummer.  It will be very useful to be able to query API usage to avoid exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot detect via the API that the request limit has been reached. There are no events that are fired and the API does not expose a function or property to determine that the API quota has been reached.

Google has decided that this is not a feature they will implement.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830575#comment12

Answer (score 0):

@kilogauss I would disagree that falling back to static Google Map is not an option.

According to https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits

*"Web sites and applications using the Google Maps API may at no cost generate up to 25,000 map loads per day **FOR EACH** service"* (capitalization and boldface mine).

And on https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_pricing, you can see that JS Maps API v3 and Static Maps API are separate services.