# Check Google Maps API key before using

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking to have an array of Google Map API keys like so:

```
var keys = [
  "key1",
  "key2",
  "key3"
];
```

I've checked the documentation and can't see see anything that I need - Basically I'd like to have some logic that checks the first key and if it hasn't reached it's usage limit to use that key, if it HAS reached it's limit to then check the second key. Is this possible?

Carl

Comment: Oh course this would break the terms and conditions of google... The usage limits are there to stop people abusing the system. If you need to up your usage limit google charge for this..

Comment: My bad, didn't even think about that. You are right, thanks, Carl

Answer (score -1):

google maps return "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" status if a limit has been reached. you can create a request, and check if that is what is returned,.. in which case, you know check for the next key. 
check this[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430147/detect-google-maps-api-quota-limit)

Comment: So what your saying is this is a duplicate? If you think a question is a duplicate you should flag it as such not post an answer pointing at the duplicate question