# Hitting google maps daily quota limit, when nowhere near that amount of traffic

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've searched extensively, but haven't found anything that matches my problem.  We have a site that is hitting our daily 25000 hit javascript API limit.  I know, I know, that sounds common enough, but I'm sure it's the daily limit and not the IP or hourly one because the Maps dashboard shows us getting about 1800 hits/hr right now. Google Analytics on the site, however shows the maps page only getting about a 20th of that on the locations page.  (~4000 hits/day)
We have the API key HTTP Referrer security set so it's unlikely we are getting maps DOS'd.  We've also generated a new account and API key, and confirmed that all of the traffic immediately switched over.
I've confirmed that the site is only making one QuotaService request per locations pageload as well.

Ok, now here's where things get weird.  Our analytics traffic shows a pretty standard day/night sine wave of pageloads.  Our Maps traffic is all over the place, though.  The low point from Oct 22, 5am to Oct 23, 10:30pm shows the hits almost exactly as I would expect.  .01 to .02 hits/s in the middle of the night, and .04 to .05 h/s in the middle of the day.  The traffic during all other time I can't account for.  Any thoughts, or tools to help track this down would be appreciated.

[Maps traffic pattern screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1pFz.jpg)

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430147/detect-google-maps-api-quota-limit) if it can help you.