# Calculate hits left in my

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

i am calculating distances between two places using the google api.

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?&origins={origin}&destinations={destination}&key={api_key}
```

i have a api key, which has usage limit of 2500 requests per day.

i am calculating multiple distances in my .py program.
 when the key usage limits exceeds, i get query over limit error.

I want to know how many hits are left in my api.

is there any way of doing it programatically?

Comment: Count your uses?

Comment: @ScottHunter say i am using the key for n distance computations,
so i want to find how many keys are left i.e. (2500-n), and i dont have a track of n.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this a comment but I'm not allowed to.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8714638/5914299

But why not check for the day and keep a counter. When reached 2500 stop requesting the API and when an new day arrives reset the counter?